# Is it possible to wrap each test execution in XUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, exception, xunit

I have an exception being thrown by multiple tests that contain some useful information. By default the failed unit test log does not contain that information since it is a property of a custom exception.

I can do this:

```
try
{
   // Run code that casts MyException
}
catch (MyException e)
{
   // Extra logging for e.SomeProperty
   throw;
}
```

But then I will have to do this for each and every test. Is there somewhere I can do this for all of the tests of a test class? Kind of like a middleware in Asp.Net.

Or some alternative way to handle exception before XUnit.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyException` is a type you define, you may want to consider changing `Exception.Message` to be a concatenation of what the user puts in, and the useful information, since generally you want to make the Message be as helpful to you as possible.

```cs
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(string message)
        : base($"{message}: {SomeProperty}") { }

    // other constructors...

    public required object SomeProperty { get; init; }
}
```

If however you cannot or don't want to, you could also have a helper function for your tests that uses a callback within a try-catch and rethrow the exception with more appropriate information. Exceptions can wrap inside other exceptions which allows each exception to be shown.

```cs
static void Do(Action act)
{
    try
    {
        act();
    }
    catch (MyException my)
    {
        throw new($"something something foobar: {my.SomeProperty}", my);
    }
}
```

(Bare in mind some linters will tell you throwing a bare `Exception` is bad, but for tests it shouldn't matter.)

You can finally use it in your tests like so:

```cs
[Fact]
void Foo() => Do(() =>
{
    // your function goes here!
    // you can simply throw the exception to test out how it'll look like
    throw new MyException("yay") { SomeProperty = "context value" };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, the exception is unfortunately not mine or I would have done what you suggest. I have already though about this extra method, but I would really like to do it somehow in a more uniform way than this if possible.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing so is with a method decorator library such as [`MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody`](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody). Make an `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` and override `OnException` with similar logic to `Do`. Hope that helps!